# Spark 2.3 Multiplicacion of Three Columns giving Null

Tags: scala, apache-spark

When I Try to multiply few columns within a DataFrame

```
val finalDFSec = otroDF
  .withColumn("acct_balance_amount",otroDF.col("acct_balance_amount") * (outputDF.col("SecPercent")) * (outputDF.col("notional_percent")))
```

Below the precision and data sample of each Column

[image]

I am getting Null as a result. same code is working in Spark 1.x

Any thoughts?

Thanks

How can I get the correct multiplication result?

Answer (score 0):

Can you try setting spark.sql.decimalOperations.allowPrecisionLoss=false
this parameter is by default set to true which might be causing a precision loss resulting in nulls

Comment: yeap, tried that but still not working.

Comment: can you try setting the precision to same value for all the three columns or try typecasting the columns in the spark code. The different precisions can cause issues sometimes. Also it would be great if you could give a sample code to create the otroDF df as well to replicate the issue. Thanks.